# How should I multi-thread my java script that talks to a database

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

Here's what my script does:

It parses a document that has 27 million lines, line-by-line. I take each line, parse it, and insert the necessary information into a database table (using JDBC).

The problem is, the preparedStatement.executeUpdate() method is not asynchronous, so it waits until it returns, and this is where my bottleneck is. It takes about 2 days to parse 27 million lines :(

Since JDBC has no async support, I want to wrap each executeUpdate() call in a thread. Should I create a new thread each time? Or should I use a thread pool, and how should I create that thread pool?

I'm worried that since the parsing of the line takes hardly any time, the amount of active tasks waiting in the thread pool will outnumber the amount of available threads and it will go back to being linear, with the bottleneck being tasks waiting for open threads.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create an Executor with a fixed number of threads (whatever gives the best performance)
2. create a BlockingQueue with a max size, say 100
3. submit the desired number of workers to the Executor, each has a reference to the BlockingQueue and their own Connection/PreparedStatement
4. main thread parses the file and `put()` lines on the BlockingQueue
5. worker threads `take()` a line from the BlockingQueue and update the database

(this is a basic producer/consumer multi-threading scenario)

Comment: How do I submit workers to the Executor? Is this through the execute(Runnable) method? Ideally I'll want to create a fixed number of workers that I can reuse, right?

Comment: I made a fixed number of workers (each implementing runnable), whose run methods have a while(true) loop take()ing from the blocking queue.